# ec2 instance and load balancer reverse proxy Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-reverse-proxy, amazon-elb

I am a bit confused about the Nginx configuration when it come to a load balancer.

This is my situation.

On aws I have a load balancer to control the traffic of 2 ec2 instances.

the default configuration of Nginx works just fine, in fact if I open directly the ec2 instances IP in my browser I see the nginx page. Same if I hit the load balancer dns name I see the nginx default page.

For demonstration purpose. I configured my nginx.conf as follow:

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    listen vm-ip:80;

    server_name vm-ip;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    server_tokens  off; # disable the Server nginx header 

    # enable gzip
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
        text/plain
        text/css
        text/js
        text/xml
        text/javascript
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/rss+xml
        image/svg+xml;

    location / {
        # try_files $uri /index.html; # redirect all request to index.html
        proxy_pass https://<dns of website I want to be redirected to>;

    }
}
```

I set the same nginx.conf for both ec2 instances. After this configuration I tried to hit the ip of the ec2 instance directly and I was redirected correctly to the website I wanted. But here is the problem, when I try to do the same opening the load balancer in my browser, I still see the nginx default page.

Can anyone explain me please what am I doing wrong here?

and please if my question is not clear enough, just ask me more info and I will be more than happy to provide an answer.

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved. The issue was the `server_name` I had to point it to the load balancer A record.